# Neo: Class name of Node?

Tags: neo4j

This question may seem a little bit naive, but do nodes have class names? I'm new to Neo4j and I've been looking at examples of how it is implemented in web frameworks, Rails especially. It seems like each node obviously holds the values of the class it belongs to, but, unless I'm misinformed, they don't seem to have class/table names like MySQL would have (eg table 'users'). If this isn't true, then why am I seeing so many examples of instantiated nodes with just the class fields and not the actual class name? If this is true, how would I refer to all nodes of a certain class (or create them)? Through their edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Neo4J Labels](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels).  A label is a way of, well, labeling a node in neo4j according to a certain class it might belong to.  So you might create a node with the label "Person".  This isn't exactly what you mean by a "class" but a lot of people use it in roughly the same way.

By labeling nodes with class names that are relevant for your domain, you get the ability to query all of them, and only those nodes of a certain "class".   Example:

```
MATCH (user:Person)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:Person) RETURN user, friend
```

This query specifies that "user" and "friend" must both be labeled "Person", which I think is pretty close to what you want.